# Email Sending: Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, email

I have written a simple class for sending email. (.NET 4.5, VS 2012). I want to improve this class to find errors and attach files.

```
public class MyEmailClass
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        public MyEmailClass()
        {
            client.Port = 587;
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myaddress@gmail.com", "mypassword");
        }

        public string sendEmail(MailAddress fromAddress, string toAddresses, string subject, string emailBody, string ccAddresses = "", string bccAddresses = "")
        {
            client.Timeout = 100000;//more than 1 s

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

            message.From = fromAddress;
            message.To.Add(toAddresses);
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = emailBody;
            if (ccAddresses != "") { message.CC.Add(ccAddresses); }
            if (bccAddresses != "") { message.Bcc.Add(bccAddresses); }

            message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

            client.Send(message);
            // Clean up.
            message.Dispose();

            return "Mail Sent";
        }

    }
```

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated. (If I can use any pre-written class/package for this purpose, suggest me.)

Thannk you! Ruby.

Comment: Find errors in what? what errors are you having?

Comment: I would probably add try catch.

Comment: I would put MailMessage in using(...)

Comment: Needs to implement `IDisposable` to dispose of `client`. But what does this achieve: the configuration (in your constructor) should be in the application's config file, and the `sendEmail` function adds very little other than assuming some options (like HTML body). Also you're not following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code reviews (assuming it works) should be posed to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll try : try- catch. | where can I add - client.Dispose(); in this class? | How to attach file? Thanks

Comment: Yes. I think it is better to use - using(...), than a constructor and client.Dispose();. But if I'm sending 500 mails at a time, is it efficient? Thanks Stanley.